# Spring boot test wrong configuration classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, junit, apache-kafka

I am trying to test my repository layer using Spring Boot 2.0.1 but when I run my test class, Spring tries to instantiate a Config class not from the test package.

Here is the test code:

TestConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = {TestDatabaseConfig.class})
@Profile("local")
public class TestConfig {

}
```

TestDatabaseConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "logEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "logTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "it.xxx.yyy.repository.log" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"it.xxx.yyy.model.log", "it.xxx.yyy.common"})
@Profile("local")
public class TestDatabaseConfig {

@Bean("logDataSourceProperties")
public DataSourceProperties logDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}


@Bean(name = "logDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("logDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .addScript("classpath:schema.sql")
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "logEntityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean logEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                      @Qualifier("logDataSource") DataSource logDataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(logDataSource)
            .packages("it.xxx.model.log")
            .persistenceUnit("log")
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "logTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager logTransactionManager(@Qualifier("logEntityManagerFactory")EntityManagerFactory logEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(logEntityManagerFactory);
}
```

}

When I run this class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class LogRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ResultLogRepository resultLogRepository;

    @Test
    public void init(){
    }
}
```

it says :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaProducer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'kafka.topic.operation' in value "${kafka.topic.operation}"
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'kafka.topic.operation' in value "${kafka.topic.operation}"
```

But I cannot understand why it brings up my KafkaProducer.class from my main package (that has @Configuration annotation on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `LogRepositoryTest` test class you should indicate the alternate test configuration class that should be taken into account, in your case I think should be the `TestConfig`.

From Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config):

> If you are familiar with the Spring Test Framework, you may be used to using `@ContextConfiguration(classes=…​)` in order to specify which Spring `@Configuration` to load. Alternatively, you might have often used nested `@Configuration` classes within your test.

So annotate `LogRepositoryTest` with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public class LogRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ResultLogRepository resultLogRepository;

    @Test
    public void init(){
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also annotate your configuration class with:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

Something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "logEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "logTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "it.xxx.yyy.repository.log" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"it.xxx.yyy.model.log", "it.xxx.yyy.common"})
@Profile("local")
public class TestDatabaseConfig {
//...
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

For error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: logDataSourceProperties,spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties

Completely remove the method:

```
@Bean("logDataSourceProperties")
public DataSourceProperties logDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}
```

and change your:

```
@Bean(name = "logDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("logDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties properties) {
 // ...
}
```

to:

```
@Bean(name = "logDataSource")
public DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: OK I did like you said, now I am getting this exception: 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: this probably means that `logEntityManagerFactory()` which creates the `EntityManagerFactoryBuilder` bean in your `TestDatabaseConfig` is not loaded. Can you debug your project to see if placing breakpoints there work? Else try to change `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})` with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDatabaseConfig.class})`

Comment: I added a breakpoint there but I have no clue of what is failing... It prints NoSuchBeanDefinitionException etc. without more information, even in DEBUG.

Comment: So..it doesn't stop to the breakpoint? Just to make sure, place your breakpoint at line: `return builder.dataSource(logDataSource)`

Comment: Does it stop at any breakpoint inside `TestDatabaseConfig`? This means that your config class is not seen at all which is strange since it is declared in `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestDatabaseConfig.class})`

Comment: Also add the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation in your configuration class

Comment: Ok now it hits the breakpoint but I get `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: logDataSourceProperties,spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties`